# What is the best way to add command api with django-tastypie?

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

I have the following model and I want to allow user to join the event with API
with django-tastypie.

```
# Conceptual, may not work.
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=255)
    users = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def join(self, user):
        self.users.add(user)
    def leave(self, user):
        self.users.remove(user)

# join the events with API like...
jQuery.post(
    '/api/v1/events/1/join',
    function(data) {
        // data should be a joined user instance
        // or whatever
        alert(data.username + " has joined.");
    },
);
```

But I don't know the best way to do this. Should I create `EventJoinResource` like

```
# Conceptual, may not work.
class EventJoinResource(Resource):
    action = fields.CharField(attribute='action')

    def post_detail(self, request, **kwargs):
        pk = kwargs.get('pk')
        action = kwargs.get('action')
        instance = Event.objects.get(pk=pk)
        getattr(instance, action)(request.user)

resource = EventJoinResource()

# ??? I don't know how to write this with django-tastypie urls
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('r'^api/v1/events/(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<action>join|leave)/$', include(resource.urls)),
)
```

What should I do? Any suggestions are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could create the "EventResource". Then you could have different events for users joining, users leaving and any other action. So basically it would probably be good to have also "EventTypeResource".

Then every time an event occurs, you would simply POST to "EventResource" specifying the type of the event (by specifying the element of EventTypeResource collection) and any extra data, like this:

```
jQuery.ajax ( {
    url : '/api/v1/events/', #note the collection URI not the element URI
    data : {
        type : '/api/v1/event-types/<pk_of_the_event_type', #URI of EventTypeResource
        extra_data : { ... }
    },
    success : function(data) {
        // data should be a joined user instance
        // or whatever
        alert(data.username + " has joined.");
    }
);
```

Comment: Sorro I don't get what you mean with ``EventTypeResource``. With your suggestion, how can a user join a particular event? Should I passed type like "join" for join and "leave" for leave and 'update' for updating events or whatever???

Comment: In a RESTful API there should be no operations or method calls (which are characteristic for RPC-like APIs). Therefore you should just create an event rather than join it (perform operation on it). EventTypeResource helps you distinguish between different events, like join or leave. So yes, in the simplest form EventTypeResource could have just one attribute "label" or "name" and be related to EventResource via a ToOneField(). Then the "user joining an event" is expressed as EventResource being created of related EventTypeResource "join".